# Which driver is resuming my USB device?

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, sniffing

I have a USB device that correctly enters in Suspend state, but it gets Resumed after a couple of seconds, then goes back to Suspend state and the loop continues.

This happens on my notebook (Windows 10 x64) and a Desktop PC (Windows 7 x64), but not on a third notebook similar to mine (Windows 10 x64).

I'm suspecting that the first two machines has installed some kind of USB Driver that continuously polls my device, so it gets resumed.

I've traced the activity using an external USB analyzer (Ellisys Explorer 260), here is a screen showing that after the devices goes on Suspend (000 time), a loop of packets like DEVICE_REMOTE_WAKEUP or SET_IDLE continues. While I should not see any particular activity (right?).

[image]

Is there a program to check which Process (so an higher-level tracer) is sending packets to my device?

Comment: You can prevent the device sleeping from devmgmt if you'd like, any query targetted at a device will wake it up, it does not need to be a driver (directly) so it'll probably be hard to trace, does that device have a software attached to it ?

Does powercfg -devicequery wake_armed help in someway ? (probably not)

Comment: Can you try USBTreeView to see if any parameters give you any clue? 

https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html#download